# serialize form data and post to generic handler

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Without using jQuery, is it possible to serialize my form data and POST it to my generic handler?

```
<form>
<input id="firstname" type="text">
<input type="hidden" id="serobj"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Can't you just set the `action` attribute on the form to point to the handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like the JSON.stringify()?

http://www.json.org/js.html

And to submit you can use something like:

```
<form name="myform" action="test.php">
   <input id="firstname" type="text">
   <input type="hidden" id="serobj"/>

    <input type="submit" onclick="javascript: submitform()">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform() {
   document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
```